# Hot Towel gulp build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, hottowel

I am working through the tutorial about Node.js found here: http://www.johnpapa.net/get-up-and-running-with-node-and-visual-studio/

I can get the app to run in
    glup serve-dev --sync. 
This works well. The problem I have it with
    gulp serve-build --sync 
or
    gulp build
I get this error:

Any idea?

gulp build
06:06:12] Using gulpfile F:\Projects\myapp\gulpfile.js
06:06:12] Starting 'wiredep'...
06:06:12] Wiring the bower dependencies into the html
06:06:12] Starting 'clean-styles'...
06:06:12] Cleaning: ./.tmp/**/*.css,./build/styles/***/.css
06:06:12] Starting 'clean-code'...
06:06:12] Cleaning: ./.tmp/**/*.js,./build/js/***/.js,./build/**/*.html

06:06:12] Starting 'vet'...

06:06:12] Analyzing source with JSHint and JSCS

06:06:13] Starting 'clean-images'...

06:06:13] Cleaning: ./build/images/***/.*
06:06:13] Starting 'clean-fonts'...
06:06:13] Cleaning: ./build/fonts/**/*.*

06:06:13] Finished 'clean-images' after 83 ms

06:06:13] Starting 'images'...

06:06:13] Compressing and copying images

06:06:15] Finished 'clean-fonts' after 2.56 s

06:06:15] Starting 'fonts'...

06:06:15] Copying fonts

06:06:15] Finished 'clean-styles' after 3.36 s

06:06:15] Starting 'styles'...

06:06:15] Compiling Less --> CSS

06:06:16] Finished 'clean-code' after 4.12 s

06:06:16] Starting 'templatecache'...

06:06:16] Creating an AngularJS $templateCache

06:06:18] Finished 'styles' after 2.39 s

06:06:18] Finished 'templatecache' after 1.96 s

06:06:18] Finished 'fonts' after 2.87 s

06:06:19] gulp-inject 27 files into index.html.

06:06:19] Finished 'wiredep' after 6.87 s

06:06:19] Starting 'inject'...

06:06:19] Wire up css into the html, after files are ready

06:06:19] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.

06:06:19] Finished 'inject' after 153 ms

06:06:20] Finished 'vet' after 7.63 s

06:06:20] Starting 'test'...

ARN [config]: "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts

NFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/

NFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

ARN [watcher]: Pattern "F:/Projects/myapp/src/client/tests/server-integration/**/*.spec.js" does not match any file.
06:06:22] gulp-imagemin: Minified 4 images (saved 3.37 kB - 10.7%)
06:06:22] Finished 'images' after 8.84 s
NFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket vlORQyl9XHgRhe6r6u7k with id 8196448
hantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 8): Executed 39 of 39 SUCCESS (0.519 secs / 0.07 secs)

============================== Coverage summary ===============================
tatements   : 87.69% ( 235/268 )
ranches     : 50% ( 20/40 )
unctions    : 84.62% ( 77/91 )

## ines        : 87.55% ( 232/265 )

06:06:25] Karma completed
06:06:25] Finished 'test' after 5.45 s
06:06:25] Starting 'optimize'...
06:06:25] Optimizing the js, css, and html
06:06:27] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\build\es5\ng-annotate-main.js:330
   target.$methodName = method.name;
                      ^
ypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '$methodName' of false
 at matchRegular (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\build\es5\ng-annotate-main.js:330:24)
 at match (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\build\es5\ng-annotate-main.js:36:66)
 at traverse.post (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\build\es5\ng-annotate-main.js:995:23)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:50:13)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:41:25)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:41:25)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:41:25)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:44:21)
 at visit (F:\Projects\myapp\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\ng-annotate\node_modules\ordered-ast-traverse\ordered-ast-traverse.js:41:25)
...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with ng-annotate using generator-gulp-angular.

Comment: I resolved my issue by changing the dependency on gulp-ng-annotate to latest from 0.3.6.  Latest was 0.5.2

Comment: How do I change the dependency on gulp-ng-annotate?

Comment: Open your **package.json** and replace 
**"gulp-ng-annotate": "~0.3.6"** with  
**"gulp-ng-annotate": "~0.5.2".** 
After run **"npm update".**

Comment: I did this and I am getting the same error. Is there a way to check if my gulp-ng-annotate was updated? I tried to run "gulp-ng-annotate --version" this did not work...

Comment: **> npm view gulp-ng-annotate version**

Comment: Got it working. I needed to do this: "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2" and not "gulp-ng-annotate": "~0.5.2".

Comment: @DonSinDRom if you can add your comment as an answer with the ^ I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open your **package.json** and replace **"gulp-ng-annotate": "~0.3.6"** with **"gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2".**

After run **"npm update".**